# React Select conditionally render the types for multi vs standard select?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I'm trying to get the prop types working for react-select. I've built a wrapper around it that determines whether it can be multi or not

my onChange function looks like so:

```
  onChange: (
    newValue: IsMulti extends boolean
      ? MultiValue<Option>
      : SingleValue<Option>,
    actionMeta: ActionMeta<Option>,
  ) => void
```

but this gives me: `Type 'readonly Option[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Option': label, value`

`IsMulti` is coming from:
`type MySelectProps<Variables, OnQueryData, IsMulti>` and I'm just hardcoding in `false` for now

not sure how to conditionally change the props based off single or multi value?

Comment: Where `MultiValue`, `SingleValue`, `ActionMeta`, `Option` are coming from? It feels like you mixed up typings and somewhere you expected to pass single option , but instead - you passing array of options.

Comment: they all come from react select